# Addressing email to more than one person

Tags: email, salutations

Which ones are correct:

'Hi All' or is it 'Hi all'. (A)ll does not look right

'Hi Peter/John' or 'Hi Peter, John' when you want to specifically address the e-mail to two people, i.e. so they clearly know they are the main addresseess and appear in 'to' and all the rest, if any, are in the 'cc'.

Comment: Why do you think the *all* needs capitalization? Because it replaces 'Peter, John, Paul,' etc.,? :) Compare: 'Dear Uncle,'.

Comment: What's addresseesses, Precious?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to capitalise because 'all' is a common noun.

In the UK it's still more common to use a '/' or 'and' than a serial comma when addressing more than one person in an email. But then names are sometimes omitted entirely.